# Find the area of a triangle whose vertices cut the sides of $ABC$ in thirds

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have to find the area of $F$, given the following configuration:

$\hspace1in$[image]
What to do?

Comment: See [triangle in a triangle](http://nrich.maths.org/4322).

Answer (score 2):

Since $BA'=\frac{1}{3}BC$ and so on, we have:
$$ [AB'C']=[A'BC']=[A'B'C] = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}[ABC] \tag{1}$$
so the area of $F$ is just one third of the area of $ABC$.

The latter can be computed through [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula):
$$ [ABC]=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{108\cdot 6\cdot 48\cdot 54}=324, \tag{2}$$
so:

> $$ F = \color{red}{108}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: $ABC', AB'C$ and $A'BC$ are all colinear triples, and thus have area $0$. Maybe you mean $A'B'C, A'BC'$ and $AB'C'$?

Comment: @Arthur: sure, sorry, typo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

I've introduced some notations on your figure:

[image]

The angles can be calculated by the law of cosine. For example, for $\alpha$ we have

$$27^2=30^2+51^2-2\cdot30\cdot 51\cdot \cos(\alpha).$$

Having calculated the angles, we can calculate $c,c',c''$ by the law of cosines.

Having calculated these lengths we can calculate one of the angles of the small (shaded) triangle (by the law of cosines).

...